# Why is the Visual Tree empty on an ItemsControl Container?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, visualtreehelper

I have a requirement get access to particular visual elements in any given view.  This is easy on statically declared items in xaml since they are available anytime. However, datatemplated ItemsControls generate their visual tree at runtime.  For example, a `TabControl` bound to a Collection of child ViewModels.

I need access to views once they are created by the `ItemContainerGenerator`.  I tried hooking up to the `StatusChanged` event on the `ItemContainerGenerator` and it successfully fires, and I can successfully get hold of (in the case of a `TabControl`) the `TabItem` container.  However, when I use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get it's children, it's empty.

Is there any reason why the visual tree of the `TabItem` is empty?  Is there a another event I should be hooking onto to achieve this?

Comment: This looks like your intent is obscure and evil, and that you're trying to enslave the entire human race with your code (or even worse, accessing the UI elements in code). May I ask what do you want that for?

Comment: It's really difficult to justify and I asked exactly the same question as you when I first came across the issue.  I am searching for a given control type in order to attach an object to every instance of it, it ain't pretty but in this particular circumstance, necessary.  Ultimately I can work around it, but I am so far down this path I'm hoping to see it through for completions sake if nothing else.